# Excel consolidate duplicate rows by summing the values

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, redundancy

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns.

```
    CON ITE
    TAT 5
    T   6
    TAG 7
    GAT 3
    T   8
    GAT 2
    TAG 6
    TAT 3
```

I would like to remove the duplicates in first column (CON) by summing the values in the second column corresponding to the repeating rows. Im using Excel consolidate to get the work done but Excel consolidates data in this manner

```
    CON ITE
    TAT 5
        6
        7
        3
        8
        2
        6
        3
```

Is there any way to properly consolidate this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding as an answer so that I can show results.*

Not sure if versions will have an impact, but I am using `2007` and it worked, seemingly fine.  Using your data, here are my "Consolidate" results:

```
CON
TAT     8
T      14
TAG    13
GAT     5
```

Did you select "Use Labels In Left Column"?

Are you looking for something different?

Did you set up your table as a range, or use the "Format As Table" function?

Comment: "use labels in left column" was not selected, thank you for sorting this issue.